# Error while trying to get user id token in FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to setup devices group using fire base messaging server
i followed the documentation step by step but at the step of getting id Token
I get this error and i can not find a solution that seems working
Documentation link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group

`com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: INVALID_AUDIENCE`

Here is the code I use:

```
private String getAccount() {
            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.google");
            if (accounts.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return accounts[0].name;
        }

        private class GetAuthToke extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            String idToken = null;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String accountName = getAccount();
                // Initialize the scope using the client ID you got from the Console.
                final String scope = "audience:server:client_id:"
                        + "*****.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                try {
                    idToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountName, scope);
    //            } catch (Exception e) {
    //                e.printStackTrace();
    //                System.out.println("exception while getting idToken: " + e.toString());
    //            }
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                    //  startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), 888);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GoogleAuthException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("nasef " + idToken);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
```

Log :

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: INVALID_AUDIENCE
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzbt(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzbu(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zzc(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
            com.mivors.customerservice.mivorscustomerservice.utils.pushNotifications.FirebaseRequest$GetAuthToke.doInBackground(FirebaseRequest.java:126)
            com.mivors.customerservice.mivorscustomerservice.utils.pushNotifications.FirebaseRequest$GetAuthToke.doInBackground(FirebaseRequest.java:116)
            android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: INVALID_AUDIENCE
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzbt(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzbu(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zzc(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
            com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
            com.mivors.customerservice.mivorscustomerservice.utils.pushNotifications.FirebaseRequest$GetAuthToke.doInBackground(FirebaseRequest.java:126)
            com.mivors.customerservice.mivorscustomerservice.utils.pushNotifications.FirebaseRequest$GetAuthToke.doInBackground(FirebaseRequest.java:116)
            android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Hi. It's hard to tell whats wrong if there isn't any code we can look at.

Comment: Thanks, i edited my post and added the code

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. Looking through it so far, this doesn't seem to be an issue with FCM, but with Auth. With that said, could you post the complete logs too?

Comment: I added the log